# How to filter the entire array based on user input using filter in JavaScript ?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, ecmascript-6

I am trying to use a filter in javascript to search on an array.
Following is my array:-

```
 "customerStatusInfoList": [
            {
                "customerId": 1110000012,
                "caseStatus": "pending",
                "customerName": "Robert",
                "dateOfRequest": "2018-12-15 00:00:00.0"
            },
            {
                "customerId": 1110000004,
                "auditorName": "DcbAdmin",
                "caseStatus": "pending",
                "customerName": "Sam",
                "dateOfRequest": "2018-12-14 12:40:04.0"
            }
        ]
```

And I am using the following function to filter the array:-

```
  filterTable = event => {
    console.log("event.target.value", event.target.value);
    console.log("rows", this.state.rows);

    if (event.target.value !== "") {
      let newRow = this.state.rows.filter(items => {
        console.log("item.name", items.customerName);
        if (items.customerName!== null)
          return items.customerName
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase());
      });

      this.setState({ rows: newRow, query: event.target.value });
    } else {
      console.log("Query string is empty ", event.target.value);
      let newRow = this.state.custList;
      console.log("new row :", newRow);
      this.setState({ query: event.target.value, rows: newRow });
    }
  };
```

I am able to filter on the customerName but when I try to filter using customerId or any other parameter I get customerId.includes is not a function.
But it works on customerName.
How can I filter on the entire table using JavaScript filter?
Any help or suggestion is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Because customerId is a number and not a string. consider doing a typeof check and base your test on the type 'string' or 'number'

Comment: `items.customerName` you are using customername here you can not filter the customerId

Comment: It'll throw that error only on `customerId` since only `customerId` is a number. Could you a write a simple function to filter and point out what's not working?

Comment: may be could add toString() before the toLowerCase()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`customerId` is an integer - you need to cast to string, e.g.:

```
return `${items.customerId}`
  .toLowerCase()
  .includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase());
```

btw, `items` is a confusing name for the variable - it's a single item

also, you can simplify things a bit by decomposing the item, i.e.:

```
let newRow = this.state.rows.filter(({customerId, customerName}) => 
  `${customerName || ''}`
    .toLowerCase()
    .includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase())
);
```

to include any row that matches `customerId`, `customerName`, or `auditorName`:

```
let newRow = this.state.rows.filter(({customerId, customerName, auditorName}) => 
  [customerId, customerName, auditorName].some(field => 
    `${field || ''}`
      .toLowerCase()
      .includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase()))
);
```

Comment: thank you but can we stick to filter in javascript rather than using jquery.

Comment: I'm not using jquery, this is a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Wow, template strings are awesome. How do I filter multiple items like customerId,customerName, and auditorName using template strings?

Comment: added that to my answer

Answer (score 1):

I added a test for type in here.

```
  filterTable = event => {
    console.log("event.target.value", event.target.value);
    console.log("rows", this.state.rows);

    if (event.target.value) {
      let newRow = this.state.rows.filter(items => {
        console.log("item.name", items.customerName);
        if(typeof event.target.value == 'string') {
        if (items.customerName!== null)
              return items.customerName
                          .toLowerCase()
                          .includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase()); 
            } else if(typeof event.target.value === 'number' {
              return items.cusomterId === event.target.value);
            }         
      });

      this.setState({ rows: newRow, query: event.target.value });
    } else {
      console.log("Query string is empty ", event.target.value);
      let newRow = this.state.custList;
      console.log("new row :", newRow);
      this.setState({ query: event.target.value, rows: newRow });
    }
  };
```

Comment: @PaulThomas is there a better way to filter the entire array using a filter.

Comment: I think you are using includes because you want partial imput support. ie. "pau" will match "paul thomas". You could convert the number to string also and this would give same functionality across all fields

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have added some pure javascipt logic which you can embed in your react component as per your need .

Here you can replace the **targetName** and **targetValue** comming from the **state** values of the component.

Having switch case will allow you to add different logic for different kind of fields.

```
const data = {
    "customerStatusInfoList": [
        {
            "customerId": 1110000012,
            "caseStatus": "pending",
            "customerName": "Robert",
            "dateOfRequest": "2018-12-15 00:00:00.0"
        },
        {
            "customerId": 1110000004,
            "auditorName": "DcbAdmin",
            "caseStatus": "pending",
            "customerName": "Sam",
            "dateOfRequest": "2018-12-14 12:40:04.0"
        }
    ]
}

const targetName = 'customerId';
const targetValue = 1110000004;

callback = (value, index, array) => {

    switch (targetName) {
        case "customerName":
            return value.customerName === targetValue;
        case "customerId":
            return value.customerId === targetValue;
        default:
            return value.customerName === targetValue;
    }
}

let result = data.customerStatusInfoList.filter(callback, this);
```